Automatically add a parameter `ITestOutputHelper` to all Test class constructors
We have a set of 15000+ xunit integration test classes in my application. We identified that the logs generated by the tests could not be correlated to the test itself unless we start using ITestOutputHelper and redirect all Serilog logs to xunit sink.
But for this, we need to modify all the 15000+ test classes' constructors to inject ITestOutputHelper outputHelper and add a code to Set the Logger to use outputHelper.
I am trying to find an aspect oriented way to do this? Is there any Fody/AOP way to do this?
I couldn't find any existing Weavers that does a constructor signature manipulation.

Maybe "primary constructors"? Maybe a common base-class (would still need a pass-thru on the main .ctor). Maybe write a Roslyn analyzer and code-fixer that does it for you? Or maybe just eat the time and do it manually?
